# How to add buttons on different tabs using TabControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have the basic tabs made and I want each tab to have a different set of buttons, but the button is added to the main window and no the tab. When i go to the code and cut the button and paste it to the tab I want it to be, it works but only for 1 button, then for the second button I get an error message:

"The object `TabItem` already has a child and cannot add `Button.TabItem` can accept only one child."

This is how the code looks like:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="394" Width="570">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="548*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl Margin="9,30,11,10" Name="tabControl1" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="tabControl1_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Name="Admin" Header="Admin">

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="Staff" Header="Staff" />
        <TabItem Name="Student" Header="Student" />
        <TabItem Name="Diary" Header="Diary" />
        <TabItem Name="Timetables" Header="Timetables" />
        <TabItem Name="Assignments" Header="Assignments" />
        <TabItem Name="Courses" Header="Courses" />
    </TabControl>
    <Menu Height="16" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,64,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118">Add/Edit Student</Button>
</Grid>
```

I want to implement the "button1" inside of the "Admin" tab

It works but it fails when I do a second button

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TabItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.aspx) is inherited from the ContentControl class, which only allows 1 object as it's content, so you need to add a control first that allows multiple objects, like a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(VS.95).aspx) or [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx), then add all of your buttons to that object.

Answer (score 7):

Add a `<StackPanel>,<Grid>, <Border>,` etc.--any Element that can contain multiple children, just like you would a `<Window>`  This holds true for ANY wpf element that can only accept a single child.  Button, ToggleButton, etc.

```
<TabItem>
<Grid>
.......
</Grid>
</TabItem
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because TabItem can only contain a single UIElement as a child. You will want to use some kind of panel (i.e. Grid, DockPanel, StackPanel, Canvas...) to arrange all of your UIElements.